# using Storage Access Framework

Tags: java, android, storage-access-framework

It works fine if you write a few data. But if you write a lot of data (which will run for a long time), it will fail with: `java.io.IOException: write failed: EBADF (Bad file number)`

Here's the code:

```
writeLargeDataToStream(new FileOutputStream(getContentResolver()
        .openFileDescriptor(data.getData(), "w").getFileDescriptor()));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need to keep the `ParcelFileDescriptor` alive from garbage collection by putting it into a local field like this:

```
private ParcelFileDescriptor descriptor;
```

And do this:

```
descriptor = getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(data.getData(), "w");
writeLargeDataToStream(new FileOutputStream(descriptor.getFileDescriptor()));
```

When you've done using that, let garbage collector know it's collectible by using:

```
descriptor = null;
```